# How to pass classic.asp forms values to sql server using stored procedure in both .asp and sql?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

1. This is my form.asp page I want to pass values to database via login.asp
2. My stored procedure applied table is signinUser
3. How to acquire form values and send to database using stored Procedure in login.asp

   Register Form

   #### Username:

   #### Password:

   ---

   Click here to go home

   ```
   </form>
   ```

   ```
   <%  

           Dim Conn,strSQL,objExec
           Dim u,p
           u = Request.Form("username")
           p = Request.Form("password")
           Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")  
           Conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=register;UID=sa;PWD=sagar;"  
           strSQL = ""  

           strSQL = strSQL &"Insert into dbo.signinUser"        
           strSQL = strSQL &"(@username,@password) "       
           strSQL = strSQL &"VALUES "  
           strSQL = strSQL &"('u','p') "   
           Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)  
           If Err.Number = 0 Then  
               Response.write("Save completed.")  
           Else  
           Response.write("Error Save ["&strSQL&"] ("&Err.Description&")")  
       End If  
       Conn.Close()  
       Set objExec = Nothing  
       Set Conn = Nothing
   ```

   %>

Comment: Can you please tell me what error you are getting.

Comment: @user3217843 They won't receive an error, but it will not do what is expected. Everytime they attempt to save the login details it will save `'u'` and `'p'` literal strings instead.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are passing literal strings into your `INSERT` statement `'u'` and `'p'`, if you're coming from a different language you probably expect the `u` and `p` variables substitute these values but this will not work in Classic ASP.

A common approach that has been used over the years is to concatenate your variables into a string which [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23863834/692942) has already suggested.

```vb
strSQL = strSQL &"Insert into dbo.signinUser"        
strSQL = strSQL &"(@username,@password) "       
strSQL = strSQL &"VALUES "  
strSQL = strSQL &"('"&u&"','"&p&"') "
```

This approach is a poor one because your login information is coming direct from a form the values could be manipulated and allow for a SQL Injection Attack.

---

A better approach is to use Parameterised Queries and in Classic ASP the object you use for this is `ADODB.Command`.

Here is an example using your code;

```vb
Dim conn, cmd, sql
Dim u, p, affected_rows

u = Request.Form("username") & ""
p = Request.Form("password") & ""

conn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=register;UID=sa;PWD=sagar;"  

sql = ""  
sql = sql & "INSERT INTO dbo.signinUser"        
sql = sql & "(@username, @password) "       
sql = sql & "VALUES (?, ?);"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  'Pass connection string and ADODB.Connection will be instantiated automatically
  'no need to use Set.
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  'Set CommandType to adCmdText ADO constant value 1
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  'Define parameters, values should reflect your field data types and size in the table.
  .Parameter.Append(.CreateParameter("@username", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100)
  .Parameter.Append(.CreateParameter("@password", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100)
  'Return affected_rows count so check INSERT worked.
  Call .Execute(affected_rows, Array(u, p))
End With
If affected_rows > 0 Then  
  Call Response.write("Save completed.")  
Else  
  Call Response.write("Error")
End If   
Set cmd = Nothing
```

---

**Some things you might find useful**

- If not using ADO constants I would seriously recommend doing so. The easiest and by far the best way to do this is [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

use

```vb
strSQL = strSQL &"Insert into dbo.signinUser"        
strSQL = strSQL &"(@username,@password) "       
strSQL = strSQL &"VALUES "  
strSQL = strSQL &"('"&u&"','"&p&"') "
```

instead of this

```vb
strSQL = strSQL &"Insert into dbo.signinUser"        
strSQL = strSQL &"(@username,@password) "       
strSQL = strSQL &"VALUES "  
strSQL = strSQL &"('u','p') "
```

You were using literal string u and p this will cause u and p store in database not actual user name and password